# Multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, submit

I have a registration form with two submit buttons. One submit button is for a free member account, and the other is for a premium member account.

My form code is

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="mail" />

//submit buttons
<input type="submit" value="signup for free member" />
<input type="submit" value="signup for premium member" />
</form>

if($_POST['name'] and $_POST['mail']){
    $user_name = $_POST['name'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail']
    //How i can know he is preimum or free ?
    }
```

Now how can I tell whether the user clicked on the free button or the premium button?

example:

```
if($_POST['free_member']){
  $member = 'free';
}else{
  $member = 'premium';
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could easily give the submit buttons a name:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="signup for free member" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="signup for premium member" />
```

Then your post will show like this:

```
var_dump($_POST['submit']); // 'signup for premium member'
```

This isn't very scalable. I'd recommend using javascript to populate a hidden field on submit. Example:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Include JQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="program_type" name="program_type" value="" />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="signup for free member" data-program-type="free" />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="signup for premium member" data-program-type="premium" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Stall form submit
    $('#program_type').val($(this).data('program-type'));
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit(); // Submit form
});
```

**PHP:**

```
var_dump($_POST['program_type']); // 'free' or 'premium'
```

Comment: Hello alien , i did't make a downvote .. it's useful replay but require java/jquery .. and the next replay is too easy and don't require any thing .. anyway voteup for your replay .. and thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Osama: His first suggestion doesn't require Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: yup .. it's my error ,, i am sorry i seen the two names is same

Comment: First solution doesn't work if you want a multilingual form (or will break if you change the submit button text) but the second solution seems to work.

Answer (score 8):

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="signup for free member" name="signup_free"/>
<input type="submit" value="signup for premium member" name="signup_premium"/>
```

PHP

```
if($_POST['signup_free'])
{
    $member = 'free';
}
elseif($_POST['signup_premium'])
{
    $member = 'premium';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Evan .. it's seems will work fine i was thinking about this idea , thank you very much

Comment: i tested it .. it's working fine , thank you again Evan Mulawski